# wincc advanced rt (v14) to kepware opc server UA via NAT

Tags: opc, wincc

Kepware opc server (kepware server ex) is running on PC 1.

On PC 2 nead to be installed WinCC Advanced RT (v14).

PC 1 and PC 2 are not in same network, there is NAT-NAT between it.

Which port supposed to be used? tcp udp?

Only one port that can be set in OPC server or some "secret ports"?

Best regards!